# Packages are missing after a successful dotnet publish

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, publish

The publish command works fine but after it is run, I have to restore the project as there are missing packages...

So if I run the following command :

> dotnet publish --runtime win-x64

Then the publish works but I have missing packages in my project right after.

BUT if I run publish without a runtime :

> dotnet publish

Then the publish works fine and I don't have any missing package.

Is it a normal behaviour? What can I do to fix this? This is annoying.

Here is my csproj file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup">
        <Version>3.3.6</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App">
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles">
        <Version>2.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore">
        <Version>12.0.13</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.MSBuild">
        <Version>12.0.13</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Analytics\MyProject.Analytics.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.ApiClient\MyProject.ApiClient.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.CommonApi\MyProject.CommonApi.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Common\MyProject.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.DbAccess\MyProject.DbAccess.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Logging\MyProject.Logging.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Messaging\MyProject.Messaging.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Model\MyProject.Model.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Settings\MyProject.Settings.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Api.Development.json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Api.json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Api.Production.json">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include=".ebextensions\never-sleep-again.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Api.PreProduction.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="MyProjectlogs\Development" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="SourceItemsFromImports" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core21) run nswag.json /variables" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutDir)References" />
</Target>
```

Edit : From the restore nugets logs, I get the following for each dependency of the project I publish

```
@   Project 'MyProject.Api' is affected (InstallCount = 0)
```

So it actually thinks something is different but doesn't seem to install anything.

Comment: Do you have 32Bit dependencies in your project? I guess these will not be published if you state 64 Bit as target

Comment: How would I check that? I have only added nuggets.

Comment: What dll is missing? Can you share a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I created a new mvc app, added the same package references, published and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Looking at the nuget restore logs, as edited in the question, it doesn't seem like anything is 'installed'. I'm really confused by this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging around, I found [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection).

The interesting part is :

> restore and build can be run implicitly as part of another command,
> like publish. When run implicitly as part of another command, they are
> provided with additional context so that the right artifacts are
> produced. When you publish with a runtime (for example, dotnet publish
> -r linux-x64), the implicit restore restores packages for the linux-x64 runtime. If you call restore explicitly, it does not restore
> runtime packages by default, because it doesn't have that context.

Basically I had a mismatch between the runtime .netcore 2.1.1 vs the restore one 2.1.X (X != 1).

The solution (explained in the link above) is to add this to the project file :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```